# Extracting values from Json Data in Swift iOS9

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, dictionary

I have the following JSon Data retrieved from the server and i want to extract the value name and store them in an array or dictionary as a model in my app. The issue is that the value returned its self is in a form of another dictionary. How can i extract values of frequency,description and amount and update them to my tableview. Below is my Json Data format that i get from the server request. I am new to swift and the concept of dictionaries and Arrays is quiet confusing to me

```
{
"payment" =     (
            {
        amount = 100;
        currency = USD;
        description = "Awesome Videos";
        frequency = Day;
    },
            {
        amount = 500;
        currency = USD;
        description = "Awesome Videos";
        frequency = Week;
    },
            {
        amount = 3000;
        currency = USD;
        description = "Awesome Videos";
        frequency = Months;
    }
);
```

}

I want to store them locally in a dictionary or an array, and update them to my tableview.

Here also is my code to fetch the data from server

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (data != nil){
            print(data)
            do {

                // let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
                let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

                print(jsonResult)
                print(jsonResult["payment_plans"])



                if let plan_list = jsonResult as? NSDictionary{
                    print("got dictionary")

                    for (key, value) in plan_list
                    {
                        print(value)
                        print("printing keys")
                        print(key)

                        if let plans = value as? NSDictionary
                        {
                            print("printing values")
                            print(plans)
                            print(plans["currency"])
                        }
                    }
                }

            }   catch{
                print("Json Serialization failed")
            }
        }

    }
    /*
    if (response != nil){
    print(response)
    }
    else{
    print(error)
    }
    }
    */
    task.resume()
}
```

I am stuck here how to extract the values that i get in the dictionary. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary it's a `key-value` storage where value in your case have AnyObject type.

To convert data into `Dictionary` or `Array` you can use

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
```

then create payments array

```
if let payments = jsonResult as? Array{ 

     *iterate here all payments 

}
```

If you want to use `for (key, value) in plan_list` you need to change it's to `for (key, value) in plan_list.enumerate()`

Comment: I managed to get the Json Data....Any idea how i can populate the data into the tableview? Seems not to work on my side. Thanks

Comment: create a property  **payments** in your class

Comment: sorry, then put all data to **payments** property and call reloadData() in table view  dataSource methods you can get data using 'if let payment = self.payments as? NSDictionary { cell.label.text = payment["description"] as? String}' don't forget you have a integer also!

Comment: I tried to call reloadData in every datasource method `self.PlanStorage.append(display_price)
                        self.PlanStorage.append(display_name)` Here PlanStoage is where am storing the data and is of an array of strings. `        cell.textLabel?.text = PlanStorage[indexPath.row]
` This is the code to populate the data but is not working

Comment: `func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        tableView.reloadData()
        return 1;
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        tableView.reloadData()
        return PlanStorage.count
    }
`

Comment: `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("choosePlan", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        tableView.reloadData()
        cell.textLabel?.text = PlanStorage[indexPath.row]
       
        return cell
    }
    `

Comment: remove reloadData here func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { tableView.reloadData() return PlanStorage.count } you need to reloadData after append all planStorages here;

Comment: self.PlanStorage.append(display_name)

Comment: and use a debugger to check all breakpoints, you can see which data in PlanStorage currently. Then you can understand whats wrong

Answer (score 2):

Hi You can iterrate your result as following:

```
if((jsonResult) != nil) {
    let swiftyJsonVar = jsonResult!
    do {
       if let dicObj = swiftyJsonVar as? NSDictionary {
           print("Response is dictionary")
           print(dicObj)
           let arrObj = dicObj["payment"] as NSArray
            // Then iterate your arrObj and do as per your need.
            //for eg.
           arrObj[0]["description"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns a fatal error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" the 'dicObj["payment"]'  returns nil

Comment: you can use like this .. dicObj["payment"] as! NSArray

Comment: I got it to work....thank you, can you recommend how i can populate the above data in the tableviewcell? It seems not working on my side. Here is my code   
    `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("choosePlan", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = PlanStorage[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }`

Comment: You can use like this to show values on your cell.....                  cell.textLabel?.text = PlanStorage[indexPath.row] [description]

Comment: And please check key before assigning to cell because it may be nil. If its nil then it may crash. So please make check for it....