# how to get particular json value in swift

Tags: json, swift

I want the size value in json object but the problem is I'm getting whole json data i want only size value to print

here is my json

```
[{
   size = {
    height = 20
    width = 10
    },
    number = 100
}]
```

here is my code

```
     do{
            let Json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)
            //print(Json as Any)

            guard let newValue = Json as? [[String: Any]] else {
                print("invalid format")
                return
            }
            print(newValue)

        }catch {
            print("Response Not Found.")
         }
```

Comment: You need to fetch size key only to print size. For reference follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736924/extracting-values-from-json-data-in-swift-ios9/40737688#40737688

Comment: can u write a code for me

Comment: My dear please try first and if you have any issue please let us know.... we will surely help you ....

Comment: I'm getting whole json data i want to only size value

Comment: Hey @username000, the model you are getting after parsing is array. You need to get to the index of that array first, then reach the key value pair. Your case will be newValue[<int index>]["Key"] or for trial you can do newValue.first["key"]

Comment: Your new value is array and array contains dictionary. So you need to first fetch dicitonary from array and then use key size to fetch your desired record.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
guard let newValue = Json as? [[String: Any]] else {
     print("invalid format")
     return
}
print(newValue["size"])
```

or if you want height & width

```
var sizeDict = newValue["size"] as! [String:Any]

print("Width - \(sizeDict["width"])")
print("Width - \(sizeDict["height"])")
```

Comment: im getting error Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: dictionary is present inside the array, newValue["size"] will be an error.
You can correct your answer stating the same.

Comment: var sizeDict = newValue[0]["size"]

Comment: foreach statment

Comment: for dict in newValue { dict["size"] }

Answer (score 3):

Please learn to read JSON, it's pretty easy, there are only two collection types:

- `[]` is array, Swift `[Any]` but in almost all cases `[[String:Any]]`, accessed with index subscription.
- `{}` is dictionary, Swift `[String:Any]`, accessed with key subscription

---

**Never use the `mutableContainers` option in Swift**, it has no effect at all.

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]] {
    for item in json {
        if let size = item["size"] as? [String:Any] {
            print(size["height"], size["width"])
        }
    }
}
```

And variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter.

PS: You have to cast the type of `height` and `width`. The output – which is actually **not** JSON – is ambiguous, you cannot see if the value is `String` or `Int`

Comment: What is (was?) the `mutableContainers` option supposed to do?

Comment: @Fehniix it’s a Objective-C related option to assign the result to an `NSMutable…` object which makes no sense in Swift. And it makes no sense anyway if the result is assigned to a `let` constant.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to extract size from newValue . Try this

```
do  {
        let Json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)
        guard let newValue = Json as? [[String: Any]],
            let size = newValue[0]["size"] as? [String:Any] else {
                return
        }
        print(size)
    }
    catch {
        print("Response Not Found.")
    }
```